# Splitting data frame every 41 rows and overwrite temporal variable inside loop in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, seq

I have this data frame (df) that has 1722 rows, and i want to generate a smaller data frames every 41 rows, like this:

```
temp1 <-df[seq(1, 41), ]
temp2 <-df[seq(42, 82), ]
temp3 <-df[seq(83, 123), ]
... (and so on until seq(1681,1722), so, there are a lot).
```

For using inside a loop that calculates qvalues.
By the way, imagine bf with random numerical data (because it has some pvalues). You can generate your own because the content is not important in this case. I want the first 41 entire rows together, and then the next 41, and so on. 
I figured there would be a more optimal way of doing this with a for loop than just typing every numeric sequence by hand as it's shown above. Or maybe not a loop, but another way of using this seq() command. Any thoughts ? Thanks !

Desired output: some kind of loop that achieves the same result as doing , but overwrite it in a temporal variable (called "temp") and then calculating the q-value. So, it's not just splitting the df, but in a way that overwrites itself in "temp". Something like this:

```
for (i in 41) {
temp<-split(df, rep(1:42, each = 41))
qvals<-qvalue(temp$p.value)
}
```

Comment: `split(df, rep(1:42, each = 41))`? This should create a list of 42 dataframes with 41 rows each.

Comment: I'm sorry, i explained the problem a bit more. I don't feel it's a duplicate anymore.

Comment: Looking for this `temp <- split(df, rep(1:42, each = 41)); lapply(temp, function(x) qvalue(x[["p.value"]])`?